# Concat/join multiple audio files into one in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, buffer, concatenation

**Edit:**

The question was marked as too broad so I will factorize it to one simple question:

How do I play a sequence of audio files from within a web page (React actually) without small gaps between plays ?

---

I have an audio file (in this case mp3 but could be any format) which was split in 100 separate files by Audacity.

I stored these files in MongoDB as binary entries to fetch them later. (Files could be stored as whole in a directory on the server if the solution is based on it)

In Node.JS with simple Buffet.concat(), I managed to join the binaries and I could download the entire file as a single mp3.

The problem is, the output file was only 3 seconds long (which is a single mp3 chunk is) but was playable for the real duration even if the player was confused about 3 seconds length. Also it was ~3MB bigger that the original complete file, probably because of headers between chunks being concatenated.

My question is, how could I possibly merge audio chunks with proper headers being in the output? I know ffmpeg can do some black magic but I mostly need a Buffer output to make the file playable as a stream inside a web page without download. That point is very important.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: MP3 is a compressed audio format, and each individual file will have it's own headers and self-contained data. You can't just concatenate the bytes together and expect it to work; you would have to decode the MP3 into raw audio data first and then concatenate the audio buffers.

Comment: Also, storing a split audio file in a database seems like a really bad idea. It should just be hosted on your server and then loaded via an [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag and played using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

Comment: @Herohtar it seems that there is currently no way to join or play audio chunks without gaps between them. I tried to play them client-side but had a very small gap between chunks. That's why I need to process them server-side and send it to client.

Comment: Why are you using chunks and not just a single file?

Comment: Have you looked at [audioconcat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audioconcat)?

Comment: @Herohtar Because I need to rearrange them on a "timeline" and let the user play the whole sound as a single one but with chunks organized in the order the user puts them

Comment: @James yes, but audioconcat saves a file on the server and I need to just stream the result to the client after processing.

Comment: I also want to precise that the files shouldn't be restricted to mp3 only. They can be any audible format inside a web page.

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried doing the concat using [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer)? You should be able to put something together using that, as the Web Audio API is intended for exactly those kinds of scenarios. Either concatenating them together, or playing each buffer in succession.

Comment: @Herohtar I tried AudioBuffer today. With buffers I can join audio files as I want but on the client side it's very slow and killing my Chrome with temp data...

Comment: @Herohtar, actually I dug deeper and wrote a better version of code and it worked like a charm, there seems to be no delay between buffers. Thanks a lot for the tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you're taking an audio file and **converting** it into many audio files.

In the second case, you're taking many binary files (yes, they're still audio files, but you're using a process that ignores that fact) and **concatenating** them into a single binary file.

Most audio files formats contain a bunch of information that describe their content (channels, bit rates, etc.). Using software designed for handling audio files, to split an audio files, generates more audio files, each with their own set of descriptive data.

Trying to concatenate those files without taking their content into consideration results in a single file containing the information for several audio files. Since most audio formats aren't designed for this scenario, some players will only see the first bit and consider the rest to be garbage while other players will tell you the content is one thing while playing something else.

Treat the files the same way at both ends of the process.

---

Javascript doesn't have a native way of easily manipulating audio the way you want. You do have a few options though:

- Find a module that interfaces with audio software. There are a number of npm modules that use ffmpeg. Doing it this way may still not get you what you want as merging audio files is not an instant process.
- Handle the audio manipulation from within the page. You can already load and play individual audio files; create/find something that can play them in sequence without needing to stitch them together. This will allow the kind of manipulation you want. When the user wants to download a finished product: send the sequence of clip ids back to the server for processing, use the above-mentioned modules to assemble them into a single audio file, then provide that file for download.

Comment: The second option is what I'm trying to achieve but with normal HTML5 Audio class it seems impossible to play the sequence without gaps between chunks. As Herohtar mentioned, maybe AudioBuffer is the way to go but I'm struggling with the docs.

Comment: @IgorVANIAN Seems like AudioBuffer treats audio a lot like canvas does with graphics. You can create buffer arrays, either blank or from source material, and then copy chunks with a basic `for` loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createScriptProcessor gives an example of adding static to a loaded audio file, but it seems feasible to change it so the played audio starts out as a zeroed buffer and the audio chunks from your database are copied in as needed.

Comment: @Outoborus, I struggled with AudioBuffer API but in the end that was the right tool. I can play a sequence with no gaps between buffers very easily now ! Thanks for the tip. You might want to add this to your answer.